# how to use select2 in asp gridview

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, datagridview, jquery-select2

```js
  $("#ddl_subject").select2();
```

how to use javascript call ID in asp gridview ItemTemplate.

```
                                   <asp:TemplateField>
                                       <ItemStyle Width="24%" BackColor="#f8f8f8" />
                                       <ItemTemplate>
                                           <asp:DropDownList Style="width: 100%"
                                               ID="ddl_subject" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="True" >
                                               <asp:ListItem Value="">-- Please Select Value --</asp:ListItem>
                                           </asp:DropDownList>
                                       </ItemTemplate>
                                   </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Want to directly embed jQuery code in GridView? Please post more code for better understanding.

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to say from the amount of code posted but a control within a gridview will not have the simple id of "ddl_subject", it will be prefixed with other things generated by asp .net.

Try doing the following selector instead:

```
$("[id$='ddl_subject']").select2();
```

This says to select any elements ending in "ddl_subject" which should find the drop down control on every row.